# How to create a matrix table to get and save integer values for future calculation

Tags: html

```
<head>
    <script>
    function generate() {
         var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("nochapter").value);
         var ch = document.getElementById("ch");
         for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            ch.appendChild(input);
         }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Prepare new assessment</h1>
    <form>
        No. of Chapter included
        <input type="text" id="nochapter" />
        <input type="button" value="set" onclick="generate()" />
        <div id="ch"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This code is used to get input from users based on the parameters which they have given in textboxes. I have to create an n*n matrix table to get the values for them. 
Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it already.
I presume you want to make a n*n matrix table of inputs?
If that is the case then just wrap your current loop in another loop that creates the rows.

Here is a working [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/declanmcd/pen/eVgqwe)

Id basically adds a new row for every n like

```
var row = document.createElement("div");
```

and adds your loop to that row.